# How to Write SQL Query Results into excel using Selenium Web Driver +Test NG

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

How do i write SQL Query Results into excel using Selenium Web Driver + Test NG

**Example :**

```
@Test(priority=5) 
    public void VerifyDataBase() {


 try {
        String query = "SELECT *  FROM [xxx].[dbo].[xxx_FEINProductionCompany] where ProductionCompanyName like'%xxx%'";
        System.out.println(query);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {

            int FEIN_ID = rs.getInt("ACA_FEINProductionCompany_ID");
            int FEIN_No = rs.getInt("FEIN");
            String ProductionCompanyName = rs.getString("ProductionCompanyName");
            String ProductionCompanyShortName = rs.getString("ProductionCompanyShortName");
            String  ModifiedDate = rs.getString("ModifiedDate");
            String Username = rs.getString("Username");
            String AddressLine1 = rs.getString("AddressLine1");
            String AddressLine2 = rs.getString("AddressLine2");
            String City = rs.getString("City");
            String State = rs.getString("State");
            int Zip = rs.getInt("Zip");
            String PhoneNumber = rs.getString("PhoneNumber");
            String ContactName = rs.getString("ContactName");
            String ContactPhone = rs.getString("ContactPhone");
            System.out.println("\nProductionCompanyName is: " + ProductionCompanyName);
            System.out.println("\nFEIN is: " + FEIN_No); 
            System.out.println("\nAddressLine2 is: " + AddressLine2);
            System.out.println("\nUsername is: " + Username);
            TestUtil.assertEquals(Username, "xxxx","FEINScreen_Username"); 
            TestUtil.assertEquals(AddressLine2, "2500 xx","FEINScreen_AddressLine2"); 
            System.out.println("\nQuery Result Set is: "+ ProductionCompanyName+"\t"+FEIN_No+"\t"+AddressLine2+"\t"+Username);
            System.out.println("\t");
        }

    }   
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use java library/dependencies like apache poi.
Selenium or TestNG do not have any capability to interact with Excel.

use below link code and pass your sql query data to in it as an Input parameter

Refer:

https://howtodoinjava.com/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

Comment: My each test case has at least 10 SQL  queries and each query will have minimum 30 columns  /  parameters of data.Is there easiest way  instead of passing one by one parameter into excel sheet.I  have to do data validation testing.Off course I am adding assertions to validate the data on particular column data return by result set, but I wanted to save the whole result set into excel for later review  purpose.

Comment: First of all thats a different question apart from this question .. if solution helps you kindly accept same.
The solution of your answer is create a excel sheet, Add Testcase number and Testcase name, now read the Excel programmatically   using loop and add the condition if your testcase if required one then read the query you add in another column vise or row wise , you can do read or write as per requirement, you just need to create an loop with logic